# How to get path of an element of a kint printed array?

Tags: 8, debugging

In D7, when you used DPM to print out an array / object, you could double click each line to get the "path" of the element (like: ['#target']['tid']). In D8 am totally missing this feature. 
I also saw on a [site](http://dannyenglander.com/blog/drupal-8-theming-tutorial-how-craft-custom-theme-hook-suggestions-and-templates) where I can see this feature. But my "stable" devel module just doesn't seems to have this feature. Am I missing a config issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to install and enable [Search kint](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_kint) module

Comment: Thank, that was it! Any ideas why is this a separate module? In D7 the devel already contained it. Any chance they get merged in the future?